# Providing multiple strings for the UI to pick the one that best fits the size

Tags: ios, text, uilabel, width

I'm pretty sure I saw something a few days ago about using an array (or a list or a set, I don't remember) of strings to be provided to a UI element like UILabel and it picks the one that best fit the available space on screen. Ie: provide `["Today is the October the 10th, 2016", "Today is 2016/10/10", "2016/10/10", "16/10/10"]` and then the label selects the one that best fits.

Is is a native iOS fonctionnality or some nice text libs or dis I just had a dream ?

Thanks.

Comment: this is not a native iOS functionality but it can be implemented with a little effort.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I'd like to avoid coding something existing. And I'm almost sure that I saw it somewhere but after 1 hour of googling, I stopped searching. If it was a dream I made, I should worry of dreaming about code ;)